# Replace na's in pandas dataframe with the mean value of two column if they don't contain na's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataset like this one

```
data = {'DATE': ['2012-01-01', '2013-05-16', '2013-05-28',
               '2013-06-05', '2013-06-07', '2014-02-02'],
               'Avarage_Temp': [21.8, 21.1, 22.8, 23.3, 14.4, np.nan],
               'Minimun_Temp': [14.4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 15.6, 18.3],
               'Maximum_Temp': [6.7, 14.4, 11.7, 16.1, np.nan, 10.0]}
```

When I execute the command

```
data['Avarage_Temp'] = data[['Minimun_Temp', 'Maximum_Temp']].mean(axis=1).round(1)
```

I get this output:

```
data = {'DATE': ['2012-01-01', '2013-05-16', '2013-05-28',
               '2013-06-05', '2013-06-07', '2014-02-02'],
               'Avarage_Temp': [10.6, 14.4, 11.7, 16.1, 15.6, 14.1],
               'Minimun_Temp': [14.4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 15.6, 18.3],
               'Maximum_Temp': [6.7, 14.4, 11.7, 16.1, np.nan, 10.0]}
```

As you can see in rows 2-5 the result is wrong, because in these rows it return the value of the non missing value(if Minimun_Temp is na, gives the value of Maximum_Temp  in the Avarage_Temp).
So I want to have as output something like the 1st and 6th row.
I want to change the value of Avarage_Temp only if the column Maximum_Temp and Minimun_Temp in this row aren't na's.
If Maximum_Temp or Minimun_Temp is na, I want to keep the value of Avarage_Temp as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `NaN`s if at least one value in `Minimun_Temp, Maximum_Temp` by parameter `skipna=False` in [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and then replace them by column `Avarage_Temp`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Avarage_Temp'] = (df[['Minimun_Temp', 'Maximum_Temp']].mean(axis=1, skipna=False)
                                                          .round(1)
                                                          .fillna(df['Avarage_Temp']))
print (df)
         DATE  Avarage_Temp  Minimun_Temp  Maximum_Temp
0  2012-01-01          10.6          14.4           6.7
1  2013-05-16          21.1           NaN          14.4
2  2013-05-28          22.8           NaN          11.7
3  2013-06-05          23.3           NaN          16.1
4  2013-06-07          14.4          15.6           NaN
5  2014-02-02          14.2          18.3          10.0
```

Another idea with [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) for `NaN`s if at least one `NaN` per rows and for mean divide by `2`:

```
df['Avarage_Temp'] = (df['Minimun_Temp'].add(df['Maximum_Temp'])
                                        .div(2)
                                        .round(1)
                                        .fillna(df['Avarage_Temp']))
print (df)
         DATE  Avarage_Temp  Minimun_Temp  Maximum_Temp
0  2012-01-01          10.6          14.4           6.7
1  2013-05-16          21.1           NaN          14.4
2  2013-05-28          22.8           NaN          11.7
3  2013-06-05          23.3           NaN          16.1
4  2013-06-07          14.4          15.6           NaN
5  2014-02-02          14.2          18.3          10.0
```